# Android: How can I disable scrolling of CalendarView

Tags: android, scroll, calendarview

Is there a way to disable scrolling in a calendarview without completely disabling the calendar date select events?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for two days and the only thing that even remotely worked was disabling the CalendarView object.

```
CalendarView cal = (CalendarView) view.findById(R.id.calView);
cal.setEnabled(false);
```

Its not perfect, but I had arrows in the same layout to move from month to month. If you find a better solution, I would be more than happy to hear it. Good luck.

Comment: I ended up creating my own custom calendar view that way I have a lot of control over the calendar. Sorry it took so long to reply.

Comment: setEnabled is not disabling the scroll of CalendarView, any other alternative ?